# Автолоадер

Tags: php

Допустим, мне нужно, чтобы автоматически инклюдились файлы (классы) из разных директорий
Но если писать автолоадер по моим знаниями, то вырисовывается следующая картина:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(is_file('controllers/' . $class . '.php'))
        include_once 'controllers/' . $class . '.php';
}
```

я проверяю наличие файла в директории controllers. Можно ли задать директории, по которым должен вестись поиск файлов?

Comment: Эта функция устарела http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы просто не искать в списке директорий?

```
foreach (array('dir1', 'dir2', 'dirN') as $dir) {
  if(is_file($dir . '/' . $class . '.php'))
    include_once $dir . '/' . $class . '.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html